# libgdx screen flashing on desktop app

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am currently working on a simple loading screen for my libgdx game however,  it has a problem.  The loading screen works flawlessly on the android project but when it comes to the desktop version it is not working.  Currently the loading screen should show "LOADING" -> "LOADING." -> "LOADING.." -> "LOADING..." , with 1 second intervals and then repeat.  When I load the game on the desktop application, it shows "LOADING" (and it is flashing like crazy) and then proceeds with the periods like it is supposed to.  The whole time everything is flashing like the refresh rate is to high or something, and it shows phantom periods in the background when they are not supposed to be there.  Can someone tell me when this is happening on the desktop version and not the Android version?  Also here is the code from the two functions of my "LoadingScreen implements Screen"

The render(float delta) function:

```
float updateTextTime = 0;
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    if (updateTextTime >= 1){                       //check to see if it has been a second
        if (periods == 0){
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   //clears the buffer bit 
        }

        textBatch.begin();                          
        font.draw(textBatch,loading.substring(0,7+periods),(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)-(textwidth/2),(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2)+(textheight/2));
        if (periods < 3){
            periods += 1;
        }else{
            periods = 0;
        }
        textBatch.end();
        updateTextTime = 0;
    }else{
        updateTextTime += delta;                    //accumlate 
    }
}
```

and the show() function:

```
    @Override
public void show() {
    textBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/ArmyChalk.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("fonts/ArmyChalk.png"),false);
    if (game.AppTypeMine == ApplicationType.Android){
        font.scale(2.0f);
    }
    textwidth = font.getBounds(loading).width;
    textheight = font.getBounds(loading).height;
}
```

FINAL SOLUTION:
Changed render() function:
        public void render(float delta) {

```
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    textBatch.begin();                          
    font.draw(textBatch,loading.substring(0,7+periods),(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2)-(textwidth/2),(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2)+(textheight/2));
    textBatch.end();

    if (updateTextTime >= 0.5){                         //check to see if it has been a second
        if (periods < 3){
            periods += 1;
        }else{
            periods = 0;
        }
        updateTextTime = 0;
    }else{
        updateTextTime += delta;                    //accumlate 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always render something in the `render` callback.

You are probably seeing double-buffering problems (OpenGL cannot tell that you didn't draw anything into the current framebuffer, so it ends up rendering whatever was left in there).

Change your code so that you always invoke the `font.draw` call.  I think you can just move the `textBatch.begin()`, `font.draw()`, and `textBatch.end()` calls outside the initial if/else block.

If you don't want render to be invoked quite so often, you can switch Libgdx to a non-continuous rendering mode (but you'll need to find a hook to kick the render calls back to life every second or so).  See http://bitiotic.com/blog/2012/10/01/enabling-non-continuous-rendering-in-libgdx/.

Comment: Your answer worked by calling those 3 functions every time in the render function.